# Which alkyl halides can not form grignard reagent

Tags: organic-chemistry, grignard-reagent

[image]

Which compounds are not useful for preparation of grignard reagents?

a) 4-chlorobut-1-yne
b) 2-chloroethan-1-amine
c) 1-bromobutan-2-ol
d) 4-bromocyclohexan-1-ol

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Is this a trick question?

Comment: @Ringo yes, sort of.  The stydent is supposed to find fault with _all_ of them.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that there are solid reasons why NONE of the materials will form Grignards unless they are modified.

1 - The alkyne proton (pKa ~25) will quench any Grignard formed to give the Mg salt

2 - The free base is already unstable in solution wrt aziridine formation/polymerisation; any added base promotes this. Any Grignard formed will also be quenched by the NH2 protons.

3- The -OH proton will quench any Grignard forming the alkoxide which is liable to form the epoxide.

4- Similarly the -OH proton will quench any Grignard forming the alkoxide which can then form the tetrahydrofuran